# Launching LSNRCTL produces an error

Tags: oracle, listener

I am trying to launch LSNRCTL on my Windows 10 64-bit laptop; Oracle 18 XE
I get this error message:

> C:\app\Owner\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin>lsnrctl
>
> LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 10-APR-2021 13:04:13
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Message 850 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=NL
> LSNRCTL>

My `ORACLE_HOME` variable is set to: C:\app\Owner\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin

[Andrew Sayer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/217655/andrew-sayer) suggested:

> Either unset your oracle_home or set it to c:\ app\Owner\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE (assuming that’s the real directory)

I followed the suggestions, here is the output:

```
C:\>lsnrctl status
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 10-APR 02114:18:42
Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.15)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

listener.ora file:

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Owner\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Owner\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.15)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

sqlnet.ora file:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

AFAIK all of the above directories exist.

[EdStevens](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/83595/edstevens) said:

> You have "TNS-12541: TNS:no listener ".  Your listener is not started.

When I try to start the listener I get this message:

```
C:\>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 10-APR-2021 17:00:21

Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 1070 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSTNS-12557: Message 12557 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
 TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
  TNS-00527: Message 527 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
```

Comment: When people ask for clarification, or you have new information to add, use the [edit] link below your original question to improve the question rather than leaving comments around the page. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts for more information. I have done my best to edit content you left in comments into the question as a demonstration. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[EdStevens](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/83595/edstevens) wrote:

> "message not found" invariably means that `ORACLE_HOME` is not set correctly.  The message file (the file with the text of all of the error messages) is located in relation to `ORACLE_HOME`. If `ORACLE_HOME` is not correct, then it can't find the message file, and all errors will cascade to "message not found".

The question author responded:

> I think I solved the problem; the Oracle service *TNS Listener* was not started. I changed the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable to: C:\app\Owner\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE -  I dropped the "\bin" directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\Owner\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE
set PATH=%PATH%;%ORACLE_HOME%\bin
lsnrctl status
```

Comment: this answer needs  some explanation